# Can anyone explain this error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a script on my page to randomly toggle the opacity of a logo element between 0 and 1. The function works fine and I don't receive any errors in my console, but CodeKit is giving me the following error when I compile:

"Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Which occurs on this line:

```
toggle(Math.random() > 0.9), setTimeout(el, 6500 * Math.random() * 0.2);
```

Can anyone explain this error and how I can fix it if there's a way? Thanks!

Comment: Check your parens ( ), you have a too many of these: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have misplaced a ")".

toggle(Math.random() > 0.***9,*** setTimeout(el, 6500 * Math.random() * 0.2)***)***;

Comment: Wonderful, no more syntax issues. Thanks!